# Netsuite Transaction Saved Search: Item Join?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to get all of the items associated with a purchase order. I've created the saved search in the UI, but I need to pass the PO's internal ID to get the correct list of items. I tried doing this in suitescript, but I can't find the correct join table for Item? Looking at the record browser, I couldn't find item. Is this not possible?

```
var poItemSearch = search.create({
                type: 'transaction',
                filters : [
                   search.createFilter({
                       name     : 'type',
                       operator : search.Operator.IS,
                       values   : 'Purchase Order'
                   }),
                   search.createFilter({
                       name     : 'internalid',
                       operator : search.Operator.ANYOF,
                       values   : poID
                   }),
                   search.createFilter({
                       name     : 'item',
                       join     : 'item',
                       operator : search.Operator.IS,
                       values   : 'Inventory Item'
                   })
                ],
                columns: [
                   search.createColumn({name : 'item'})
                   //search.createColumn({name : 'email', join : 'custrecord_sdr_prod_pref_customer'}),
                   //search.createColumn({name : 'subsidiary', join: 'custrecord_sdr_prod_pref_customer'}),
                   //search.createColumn({name : 'custrecord_sdr_prod_pref_item'}),
                   //search.createColumn({name : 'custrecord_sdr_prod_pref_qty'}),
                   //search.createColumn({name : 'quantityavailable', join: 'custrecord_sdr_prod_pref_item'})
                ]
            });
```

I get an error that Item is not an option for a join. Am I just using the wrong name?

Otherwise, how do I add a filter to an existing saved search? I can go about it this way to just filter my search results on the purchase order internal id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`item` should be the right name for the `join`, but I don't think it's the right name for the `name` of the filter. It looks like you're trying to filter on `itemtype`, though I'm not sure whether it will be `"Inventory Item"` or `"inventoryitem"`.

It is puzzling that `item` is not listed as a join in the records browser. For example, this works just fine when run in console:

```js
require(["N/search"], function (search) {
    var purchaseorderSearchObj = search.create({
       type: "purchaseorder",
       filters: [
          ["type","anyof","PurchOrd"]
       ],
       columns: [
          search.createColumn({
             name: "itemid",
             join: "item"
          })
       ]
    });
    purchaseorderSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
       console.log(result.getValue({"name":"itemid","join":"item"}));
       return true;
    });
});
```

BTW I generated this code by creating a Saved Search in the UI, then using this Chrome plugin to export it to code: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp?hl=en It's a very useful tool to have around.